# Same url for different routes laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes

I have this two routes

```
Route::get('/books/{book}', 'FrontEnd\BooksController@show');
Route::get('/books/{main_category}', 'SearchController@getProducts')->name('getProducts');
```

Is there any way I can make both running ..

Comment: i suggest you to link this route to a function that check what kind of content is, if {book} is not in book table, then show the category

Comment: You cant do that, both with conflict each other

Answer (score 3):

When the urls got the same parameter types/length or any other structure, there is no way to distinguish them.

But when there are differences you can use [regular-expression-constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints).

Answer (score 2):

You can't make them both running, as Laravel can't differentiate between these route, since they basically have the same URL. If both of your controllers show results on the same page (ex: books index), a workaround could be to make one route, with an optional parameter:

```
Route::get('/books/{book}/{main_category?}', 'FrontEnd\BooksController@show');
```

Then you can lead both routes to the same method, and make queries there depending on the parameters you get:

```
public function show(Request $request){
   $books = Book::query(); //initiate query on Book model
   if($request->book){
     $books = $books->where('...'); //Override the query with new results using book parameter
   } 
   
   if($request->main_category){
     $books = $books->where('...'); //Override the query with new results using book main_category
   }

   $books = $books->get(); //Retrieve all the results 
}
```

Note: This is not tested, just a quick idea how you could improve your code and use one controller with one method to show book results, instead of using two different controllers. Hope I could give you some ideas with this.

Here you can read more about Laravels [optional parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-optional-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

How is the Router supposed to know which route you meant with `/books/Harry Potter - And The Goblet of Fire` or `/books/Fantasy`? There is no way to distinct these routes from each other.

Your best bet would be to use query parameters to filter the books - e.g.

```
/books/?name=Harry Potter - And The Goblet Of Fire
/books/?category=Fantasy
```

But the /books/{whatever} should be reserved for the primary key of a book. So you could do something like `/books/1/author` or `/books/32784893/ratings`.

The same route would only work if you can distinguish the values for sure (as Pilan stated in his answer).